# SparkStreaming - ExitCodeException exitCode=13

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running my spark streaming application using spark-submit on yarn-cluster.
When I run it on local mode it is working fine.
But when I try to run it on yarn-cluster using spark-submit, it runs for some time and then exits with following execption.

```
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1435576266959_1208_02_000002
Exit code: 13
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=13:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the solution.

In my Spark Streaming application I had set SparkConf.setMaster("local[*]") and in spark-submit I was providing --master yarn-cluster.

So there was conflict in both the masters and it was remaining in ACCEPTED state and exiting.